# Screen goes black after a few hours, followed by 5 beeps at reboot

Tags: motherboard, gpu, black-screen-of-death

My specs:

1. **Asrock X570 pro4** motherboard. BIOS 1.72 untouched since November 2019, all was very stable until now.
2. Ryzen 3600 with tower cooler
3. 2x8GB RAM HyperX PC3200 (compatible with my motherboard on Asrock site)
4. Asus Geforce 1050 Ti Dual (nearly 3-year-old).
5. 4 chassis fans.

The issue: the screen goes black after a few moment (could be hours) since about 4 days. On reboot **it beeps 5 times** and stays black. If I unplug the computer, and reboot a couple of hours after, no beeps and it works again. The screen goes dark under windows or web surfing sometimes.

Once it goes dark, I hear fans running at full speed.

I do hesitate between two faulty components:

1. PSU, but voltages are OK. Model 80 plus, 600W, **Cougar VTE 600**
2. my Old GPU. I cleaned it, removed all the dust and replaced the thermal compound.

The system was stable since built date (November 2019). No change on it and I didn't move the case too.

Any suggestion?

[image: voltage and temps]

Edit #1: added voltage and temps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody else is having the same issue, I got a new GPU and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only happens after running some time, and fans run at full speed, and it works again after a cool-down, it might be overheating of some component *other* than CPU and GPU, since the temperatures you provided look reasonable. So, first test if additional cooling helps. Direct a moderately strong fan into one of the air **intakes** near the heatsinks (not near an *exhaust* opening). If this gives you much longer time before shutdown, then you just need to find the issue.

If you know someone who has a thermal infrared camera, such as [this cell-phone addon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00W5PRY52), look for components running particularly hot (thermal IR cameras costs quite a lot, so you might not want to buy one). You can also scan the boards with an [infrared thermometer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DMI632G), available for less than US$20.

You mentioned cleaning the GPU and replacing compound, but have you checked the CPU and its fan and heatsink?

Comment: Thank you Doc. Yesterday I ran 4 hours of 3D demo without issue. This morning, I started the computer to answer your message, after 5 min I got the black screen (and fans go full speed), it was cold. Very disappointing and I don't think it's overheating at this point.

Comment: I started (cold machine) 5 min after, and I went into the bios. After few seconds, the screen goes black. Fans'regime didn't change. I suspect more and more a dying GPU. I will test with an old 450w PSU just in case.